# Redux: Why not put actions and reducer in same file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm creating an app with Redux and am scratching my head as to why it is best to place actions and reducers in separate files. At least, that's the impression I'm getting from all the examples.

Each action, or *action creator*, appears to map to a single function that is called by a reducer (inside a switch statement). Wouldn't it be logical to keep these together in the same file? It also makes using the same constant for the action type and switch case easier, as it doesn't have to be exported/imported between files.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From Redux creator Dan Abramov:

> Many reducers may handle one action. One reducer may handle many
>   actions. Putting them together negates many benefits of how Flux and
>   Redux application scale. This leads to code bloat and unnecessary
>   coupling. You lose the flexibility of reacting to the same action from
>   different places, and your action creators start to act like
>   “setters”, coupled to a specific state shape, thus coupling the
>   components to it as well.

From the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#actions-reducer-mappings):

> We suggest you write independent small reducer functions that are each
>   responsible for updates to a specific slice of state. We call this
>   pattern “reducer composition”. A given action could be handled by all,
>   some, or none of them. This keep components decoupled from the actual
>   data changes, as one action may affect different parts of the state
>   tree, and there is no need for the component to be aware of this.

See [this conversation on twitter](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/691608868628119552) and [this issue on github](https://github.com/reduxible/reduxible/issues/8) for more information.

Comment: "Many reducers may handle one action." answered my question. Thanks. But I can't think of a situation where an action would be handled by more than one reducer.

Comment: Imagine you're part of a team working on an app for managing an airport. You're in charge of building the part of the app that handles flight status messages. Another developer is working on a different part of the app, which handles scheduling of take-offs and landings on the runways. Those two parts of the app are handled by entirely different branches of the Redux state, with different reducers. Both you and the other developer write reducers that need to respond to FLIGHT_CANCELLED actions for your particular part of the app, even if neither of you is aware of what the other is doing.

Comment: Ahh okay! Now it makes sense. So would you say it's kind of like the pub-sub pattern?

Comment: There aren't actually multiple reducers subscribing to anything. It's really just one root reducer (which can be composed from other reducers, but it's still a single function) that [gets set as the store's `currentReducer`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L57) when the store is created, or when `store.replaceReducer()` is called. When an action is dispatched, [the store's `currentState` is replaced simply by `currentState = currentReducer(currentState, action)`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L170).

Comment: No I get that. It just _resembles_ pub-sub in the sense that dispatching an action is decoupled from how it is handled, and you can handle the same action in multiple switches.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, there is a resemblance in that sense. But I wouldn't think about it in that way, since there are quite a few differences. I'd say it's more like a simple Observer pattern in which there's exactly one observer (the store's `currentReducer`). The fact that you can compose other reducers into a root reducer is a great convenience, but it's not really the same as multiple observers. It's good to remember that all of your composed reducers are ultimately a [single function](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L111-138) that receives every action.

Comment: "Many reducers may handle one action." I never thought about it before.

Comment: 1) I'm yet to see a large enough React App which uses common actions across multiple reducers and 2) Why then are actions and reducers usually shown as folders at the top level. That kind of defeats the whole purpose of compositing a large app into smaller parts.

Comment: @abhijit 1) I’d be curious why an app that doesn’t need actions decoupled from reducers would use redux in the first place. 2) I don’t think folder structure is very important, as long as it’s consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping Actions and Reducers in separate files helps keep the code modular.

It can be easier to find bugs, extend the code, and in general work on the smallest piece possible.

Example:

Saving API error messages to the Redux store can be helpful.

If I forgot to update the store with the incoming error on one of the Reducers, that could be tough to find across multiple files.

If I'm looking at multiple Reducers in the same file, it'll be easier to see that one of them is missing the `error: action.payload` line.