# Avoiding import order/cirulcar dependency bugs with multiple reducers listening to same action in Redux

Tags: javascript, import, redux

I've been working on a Redux project using what seems to be a pretty common "module" pattern, where sets of actions, action creators, and action handlers responsible for a single slice of state are grouped together in a single file, and the reducers exported from these files are merged together into a single root reducer by combineReducers.

I have been using this pattern with some success, but I've run into some very subtle and annoying bugs when I try to have modules listen to actions exported by other modules.

The first time I ran into the problem, it was a situation where module A imports an action from module B, and module B imports an action from module A, creating a circular dependency. Fine, understandable and I can live with working around such cases.

But I've also run into situations where simply importing an action from module A in module B results in that action being undefined -- I assume based on the order in which the modules are imported or digested by combineReducers, though I haven't figured exactly how (it seems to sometimes happen even when module A is imported before module B in the rootReducer file).

So my question: is listening to the same actions in multiple reducers considered a good pattern, or something to be avoided? This seems to be what's encouraged by the Redux way of doing things, but I could be missing something.

To give a contrived example, let's say I want to keep a running log of certain actions in my application. So I have a "log" module that listens to the desired actions and updates its slice of state as appropriate.

Suppose I have a users module, which starts off:

```
export const ADD_USER = 'ADD_USER';

export function addUser (user) {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    user: user
  }
};
```

etc.

Then if I want to log when new users are added, I might do something like:

```
   import { ADD_USER } from './users';

   const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
    [ADD_USER]: (state, action) => {
       return [
         ...state,
         'Added user: ' + action.user.name
       ];
     }
   }
   const initialState = []
   export default function logReducer (state = initialState, action) {
      const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]
      return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
   }
```

Most of the time this approach works fine. But sometimes ADD_USER will be undefined at the time of import, and so the action handler will (quietly) miss that action. Very annoying!

If this is indeed the way to go, how should I avoid these bugs? The obvious solution seems to be to put the action consts in a single actions.js file that's imported before all the modules, but that seems to defeat the point of modularization. Another option would be to just write the action handler like:

```
ADD_USER: (state, action) => {}
```

When listening to a "foreign' action. But then why define and export them as constants at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Redux absolutely encourages having multiple reducers responding to the same actions.  This is why the typical basic Redux file structure would indeed have separate files for action constants - they could be imported by multiple separate reducer files, and possibly separate action creator files as well.

The "ducks" or "modules" structure *is* somewhat popular, and certainly a valid approach for organizing your code, but also predicated on the idea that only one set of reducers would ever respond to a given action.  While the "ducks" spec does suggest exporting the action constants from a module, the implication is that you wouldn't actually have these mutual dependencies because no other modules would/should care about what's going on in another module.

For what it's worth, Dan Abramov, the creator of Redux, is very much a proponent of arbitrary reducers handling the same actions, and generally disagrees with the "ducks" approach.  Obviously just one opinion, and you should absolutely feel free to do whatever actually works best for your own application, but something to consider.

Ultimately, I think the answer is that you're trying to use a "modularized" approach, but finding that the needed behavior really isn't "modularized" after all.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I also found this, explaining Dan Abramov's view, which could be helpful to anyone who comes across my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37116923/5059128