# Redux can I use one action type in separate reducers?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a situation in my Redux application where I currently have 3 separate reducers that handle the fetching of data from an api. An example of one of my reducers would be:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        allOrders: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Note the loading and error states, these are identical in each current reducer and will be for any subsequent reducers I write that involve fetching data from the api.

I would like to add a further reducer that is used only for the loading and error pieces of state. The other 3 would store the data.

This would give me:

Data reducers x 3

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: []
  // any other state in the future
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        allOrders: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Loading / Error reducer (handles loading / error for entire app)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  loading: false,
  error: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_ALL_ORDERS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

As you can see this means the GET_ALL_ORDER_SUCCESS action type will be used in 2 separate reducers. My question is, is this ok? or does it go against convention?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In redux style guide it is strongly recommended to do this. Here is link https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think that's perfectly fine. There is no place to states that Actions and Reducers have a 1:1 mapping. In fact, creator of Redux explicitly says that there is no relation between them, many reducers can react to a single actions, a single reducer can react to multiple actions.

I think he says it best: https://github.com/reduxible/reduxible/issues/8

Tweet: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/691608868628119552

Relevant SO: [Redux: Why not put actions and reducer in same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111300/redux-why-not-put-actions-and-reducer-in-same-file)

Comment: Thanks @julianljk I have implemented the solution and it seems to work very well but I just wanted clarification it wasn't gonna bite me in the @£$ at a later stage.

Comment: There is a trade off tho, a single action that does _everything_ is less explicit and harder to debug (if you care about logging). Where as multiple actions are more explicit. I think its about finding a balance

Comment: Absolutely.  Also see http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#actions-reducer-mappings and http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html for more details on the topic.

Comment: But how would redux'x `bindActionCreators` would be used to dispatch two reducer functions in response to a single action ?

Comment: Having a single action trigger multiple reducers helps keep each reducer from code bloat. Isolate each action concern  in it's own reducer. IE: UPDATE_USER might trigger multiple reducers for updating the user object, permissions, billing, etc.

Comment: @ilans `bindActionCreators` is not concerned with "dispatching reducers".  It's a shorthand producing closures that are equivalent to explicit `dispatch(action)` and its responsibility ends there. 
Redux only calls a single top-level reducer, but [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) builds one that always passes each action to _every_ sub-reducer.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar question if I could use the same action type name in two or more separate reducers and the answer is definitely no if there is not a very exceptional case.

Why not?

Even we write reducers separately after combining them by combineReducers function when we dispatch the action all reducers are called their switch case statements.

Reducer one:

```
export const postReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_DATA":
      const { posts } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: posts,
      };
  }
};
```

Reducer two:

```
export const commentReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_DATA":
      const { comments } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        comments: comments,
      };
  }
};
```

So when we dispatch an action with type SET_DATA both reducer will be called
and if payload value is

```
{
  comments: ['comment one', 'comment two'] 
}
```

post reducer will set its posts to undefined.

A better solution would be to name types like this:

```
case "SET_POST_DATA":

case "SET_COMMENT_DATA":
```

to avoid collision between two reducer's actions.

The convention is that when action is called there is only one reducer who is responsible to answer that action otherwise it can cause misunderstanding for other developers

Comment: "The convention is that when action is called there is only one reducer who is responsible to answer that action otherwise it can cause misunderstanding for other developers"

That is not the convention. A single action can trigger multiple reducers. Consider you have normalized entities of Folders and Files each one with its own reducer.

Comment: Ok, but why the Folders and Files reducers should handle the same action, and why not split the action for each reducer? 

What is the use case when u need to share the action for FoldersReducer and FilesReducer?

Comment: One example is when a folder record contains an array of file IDs representing the order of its files. When a file is added/removed it is also added and removed from this array. You could store a separate `index` property on each file, but then you'll need to update the index of all the files below a potential removed file.

You can definitely split actions, but each action triggers a new state reconciliation which can reduce the performance of your application. Consider the context your action will operate within and scope your actions accordingly.