# How to use single action type in different reducer function with createSlice method in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Is it possible that **multiple** reducer (which is created with createSlice method) must respond to the same action?

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const isAuthenticated = createSlice({
    name: 'isAuthenticated',
    initialState: false,
    reducers: {
        loginSuccess(state, action) {
            return true;
        },
        logout(state, action) {
            return false;
        },
    },
});

export const { loginSuccess, logout } = isAuthenticated.actions;

export default isAuthenticated.reducer;

const currentUser = createSlice({
    name: 'currenUser',
    initialState: 'jhon',
    reducers: {
        loginSuccess(state, action) {
            return 'steve';
        },
        logout() {
            return state;
        },
    },
});

export const currentUserReducer = currentUser.reducer;
```

As You can see action.type *loginSuccess* is in two different reducers since i am only exporting *loginSuccess* of isAuthenticated i can use only that action to dispatch.
i know i can export *loginSuccess* from currentUser as well but i want to dispatch only one action and change the state in two different states.

I know this can be done with vanilla redux and also redux recommend using it [Here](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action)

In short i am trying to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530661/redux-can-i-use-one-action-type-in-separate-reducers) but with createSlice method in redux-tool-kit.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [extraReducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation):

```js
const isAuthenticated = createSlice({
    name: 'isAuthenticated',
    initialState: false,
    reducers: {
        loginSuccess(state, action) {
            return true;
        },
        logout(state, action) {
            return false;
        },
    },
});

export const { loginSuccess, logout } = isAuthenticated.actions;

export default isAuthenticated.reducer;

const currentUser = createSlice({
    name: 'currenUser',
    initialState: 'jhon',
    reducers: {
        logout() {
            return state;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
      builder.addCase(isAuthenticated.actions.loginSuccess, () => {
        return 'steve'
      })
    }

});
```