# What is the meaning of actions and action types in React-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Now if i want to change value in store i should do following steps:

1. Go to constants/actionTypes file, create a line with action type
2. Go to actions and create action function
3. In each component where i use it i should create a function for mapDispatchToProps
4. In reducer i should write a logic of changing

Whats the point of such complexity? 
Will it be wrong if i will do just one file with actions which will change the state? For example:

// actions.js

```
export const setCategories = (payload, setState, currentState) => setState({ categories: payload })
export const addCategory = (payload, setState, currentState) => setState({ categories: [...currentState.category, payload] })
```

To make it work i can create just couple of universal functions for all projects

1) **getActions**, which authomaticly collects all exports from actions.js and provide them to mapDispatchToProps, so in all components we could just write

```
const mapDispatchToProps = getActions
```

code of it can be something like

// actionsDispatcher.js

```
import * as actions from 'actions'
const getActions = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  Object.keys(actions).forEach(actionName => {
    const fn = actions[actionName]
    actions[actionName] = payload => dispatch({ action: fn, payload, type: _.toSnakeCase(actionName) })
  }
  return actions
}
```

which means we pass to dispatch the function of action from actions.js

2) **setState** which will work similary to react function, but for redux state

then in reducer function we just right

```
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.action) {
    action.action(action.payload, setState, state)
  } 

  // here we make it extandable for ordinary way if required
  if (action.type === '...') {
    // ...  
  }

}
```

and nothing else...

So the question is whats wrong in such approach that will require for coder just write a function in one file 'actions.js' and call it from any component as props.someActionName(someParams) instead of changing 4 differents files?

Thank you

Comment: Please Refer [React-Redux Actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions)

Comment: Imagine you had things such as api calls, error handling, and many other functions that had to be run in order for you to update just a part of the state. With a larger more complex application, it becomes much easier to use Redux's provided framework for managing and updating global state.

Comment: @SohanPatil, i'm really sorry, what made you think i didnt read it?

Comment: @Dmitry Reutov Please refer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111300/redux-why-not-put-actions-and-reducer-in-same-file)

Comment: @DmitryReutov If you really want to put it all in one file, and it will be fine for use case, please refer to [Redux ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)

Comment: @Redline, there is no contradiction, my approach is also using redux framework and it can be extandable in some exceptional cases... But mostly it is one action type, one action creator, one reducer code, one mapDispatchToProps line. I am using the same framework but combine these 4 entities in one as they are really one in 95 percents of cases and still you can extend reducer function

Comment: @Redline, i read Abramov's answer but as i mentioned already my approach doesnt exclude his approach but just make it simplier in many many cases where actions are just setters... so with my approach you still can in some special cases do it  in ordinary way

Comment: It is to separate intention from implementation. You have the intention to increment a counter so the component dispatches `INCREMENT` how increment is implemented is in the reducer. So what you want to do is defined in actions and how you want to do it is implemented in reducers. It is to make complex requirements more manageable. If you use redux the way you use it in your question then you may as well not use it and use Context instead.

Comment: @HMR, we can say the same about any function - its name is WHAT WE WANT TO DO and its body is HOW WE WANT TO DO... but we use just one function and no problems arises

Comment: If your action changes the state then what it does and how it does it is the same thing. With redux you can have middleware and several reducers that so something depending on what is indicated needs to happen.

Comment: @HMR if it is not too difficult could you please write answer with some simple example where my approach is failed

Comment: @DmitryReutov [conventional-redux](https://github.com/mjaneczek/conventional-redux) is a slimmed down redux wrapper if you are interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux is supposed to make complex requirements easier to implement but if you have simple requirements then it makes implementing these requirements more complicated.

The [motivation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation) mentions [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)(Command Query Responsibility Segregation) that separates how you read from store (in redux with selectors and I'm a big fan of reselect) with how you write to it (with action and reducers).

The actions and reducers are the command (write) part of CQRS and is [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html), redux is sometimes referred to as an event store. This enables you to add or remove handlers (reducers or middle ware) for your events (actions) that can update the store, dispatch other events (=actions), do asynchronous stuff, write to local storage.

If you need to do all these things in one function (async fetch, write to local storage, call other functions (dispatch other actions),...) then that function becomes unmanageable.

Even if the function only calls other functions then it still needs to know the entire process of certain action. But if (for example) you had a local storage middleware that would write to storage on certain actions then no other code needs to know how or when it's called. So when logic of writing to local storage changes it is limited to the local storage middle ware.

This is the advantage of handlers (reducers, middleware) listening to events (actions), the handler only needs to know about a small portion of the process, not the entire process.

With event resourcing we also know why the state has a certain value instead of only knowing what the state is, the [article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) states:

> However there are times when we don't just want to see where we are, we also want to know how we got there.

Another big advantage of an event store is that you can re create the data by playing back the events. All this is excellently done with redux def tools.

[Here](https://read.reduxbook.com/) is a great book on React with Redux.

Answer (score 0):

[Conventional-redux](https://github.com/mjaneczek/conventional-redux) is a:

> Library for small and medium react applications, it wraps the react-redux and provides API based on convention over configuration pattern without breaking redux compatibility.

You simply define an interactor:

```
 class CounterInteractor {
  // initial state
  defaultState() {
    return 0;
  }

  // actions:
  doubleAsync() {
    setTimeout(() => { this.dispatch('counter:double') }, 500)
  }

  // reduce methods:
  onIncrement() {
    return this.state + 1;
  }

  onDouble() {
    return this.state * 2;
  }
}
```

And dispatch actions to that interactor from your connected component component. That's it!