# React Hooks and store management

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm converting an old app with functional components and redux to use react hooks and while learning it, it seems that I don't really need to use redux anymore?

Originally I'd have a store for data such as recipe and some reducers such as ADD_INGREDIENT which was more for debugging, and one of the hooks is also useReducer.

So in this scenario, if I add an ingredient to the recipe, and goto a page with another component that has access to the mixer context, is that in a way the same as having a global store in redux?

What can I do in redux or mobx that I can't already do here?

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const MixerContext = createContext()

const MixerProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([
    'Tequila',
    'Vodka',
    'Lime',
    'Egg Whites',
    'Cilantro'
  ])

  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([])
  const addToRecipe = ingredient => {
    if (!recipe.find(r => r === ingredient)) setRecipe([...recipe, ingredient])
  }

  return (
    <MixerContext.Provider
      value={{
        ingredients,
        setIngredients,
        recipe,
        setRecipe,
        addToRecipe
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MixerContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Ingredients = props => {
  const { addToRecipe, ingredients } = props
  return (
    <div style={{ border: 'solid 1px #000', padding: '25px' }}>
      <h1 style={{ marginTop: 0 }}>Ingredients</h1>
      {ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => addToRecipe(ingredient)}>{ingredient}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const Recipe = props => {
  const { recipe } = props
  return (
    <div style={{ border: 'solid 1px #000', padding: '25px' }}>
      <h1 style={{ marginTop: 0 }}>Recipes</h1>
      {recipe.map((r, idx) => <li key={idx}>{r}</li>)}
    </div>
  )
}

const JustRecipes = () => {
  const contextFromMixer = useContext(MixerContext)
  const { recipe } = contextFromMixer

  return (
    <div style={{ border: 'solid 1px #000', padding: '25px' }}>
      <h1>Recipe Page</h1>
      <Recipe recipe={recipe} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Main = () => {
  const contextFromMixer = useContext(MixerContext)
  const { ingredients, recipe, addToRecipe } = contextFromMixer

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Ingredients addToRecipe={addToRecipe} ingredients={ingredients} />
        <Recipe recipe={recipe} />
      </div>
      <Link to="/recipes">Recipes</Link>
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MixerProvider>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
        <Route path="/recipes" component={JustRecipes}/>
      </MixerProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Context definitely isn't a replacement for libraries like Redux / MobX, although for simple state sharing scenarios it can be a better alternative.

Comment: You can replace redux with context but redux is used when you want the actions (something happening in the app) separated from what needs to be done (reducer/middle ware). In the example you give all that needs to be done is coupled with the action and put into one function. In redux you also have an event store that can be used for debugging. More information about why redux is designed the way it is can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61557140/1641941)